# Any good implementation of greedy set cover for large datasets?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

This question follows from a related question of mine posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927787/finding-an-optimal-solution-that-minimizes-a-constraint). @mhum suggested that my problem falls into the *covering problem* domain. I tried encoding my question into a minimum set cover problem and currently I have a dataset in this form:

```
Set        Cost
(1,2)        1
(1)          1
(1,2,3)      2
(1)          2
(3,4)        2
(4)          3
(1,2)        3
(3,4)        4
(1,2,3,4)    4
```

The objective is to find a good set cover that covers all numbers and one that attempts to minimize the total cost. My dataset is big with at least 30000 sets (of size varying from 5-40 elements) like this. Are there any good greedy implementations to solve this or am I on my own to implement this? I am not an expert in LP but any LP-solvers (from numpy/scipy) that can solve this are also acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a well-known greedy approximation algorithm for set cover that is also easy to implement in whatever language of your choice. The algorithm itself is described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm

It is so simple that the easiest thing is just to write it from scratch.

Notably, it is also the best polynomial-time approximation algorithm known for set cover. That means that to get better worst-case performance (more compact result set) you would need to have non-polynomial running times (= slow algorithms for large sets).

Unfortunately the Wikipedia entry doesn't actually cover weighted set cover, which is the case here. The extension is simple, and is described e.g. here:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/880-S07/scribe-notes/lecture03.pdf

Some more useful notes:

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~neal/non_arxiv/Young08SetCover.pdf
http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp08/cs473/Lectures/lec20.pdf

Comment: +1 Thank you. Pardon my ignorance. I have one more question. I like the greedy version but I guess I am missing the cost version i.e. at least in my case, choosing (1,2) and (3,4) independently will give me a cost of 3 whereas choosing (1,2,3,4) will give me 4. I was hoping a cost-aware greedy set cover would take this into account but is the extension as simple as: "at each stage pick the one with maximum intersection **and** lowest cost"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the fact that the Wikipedia page actually didn't cover the weighted version, I thought it would have because it's kind of standard. Anyway, added a link to lecture notes that explain the weighted version also (weighted = with costs). You basically divide the cost of a new set to add with the number of elements it covers, and always pick the set with highest efficiency (lowest cost per covered elements). It's still provably good approximation algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much. I finished implementing it and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942312/how-do-i-make-my-implementation-of-greedy-set-cover-faster for suggestions on how to make it faster implementation-wise. I also added some more links to the answer. Once again, thank you for your help :)

Comment: My sets are going to have a few tens of items, at most, is there an exact algorithm for the weighted set cover problem?

Comment: @StavrosKorokithakis Yes, branch and bound.

Answer (score 3):

My linear time / space implementation of greedy set cover in c++ is available at github.

https://github.com/martin-steinegger/setcover

A calculation for 40.000.000 sets with avg. 10 elements per set takes around 4 Minutes on computed on Amazon AWS m2.2xlarge instances.

I still work on some tricks to improve the performance

1. remove subsets that are covered by a bigger set with [MinHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash)
2. remove all sets that just contain one element that is no other set

Comment: Wouldn't removing subsets that are covered by a bigger set not be a valid operation in the weighted set cover?  IE the smaller subsets could minimize the cost.  I'm asking out of curiousity, not suggesting this is so.

Comment: @AdamHughes sorry for the delayed response. It should be possible to remove weighted sets that are fully covered by a bigger set.