# greedy set cover algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, set

So, I picked up this code from

[How do I make my implementation of greedy set cover faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942312/how-do-i-make-my-implementation-of-greedy-set-cover-faster)

I am trying to understand sets and set cover so, I modify this a bit.

```
U = set([1,2,3,4])
R = U
S = [set([1,2]), 
     set([1]), 
     set([1,2,3]), 
     set([1]), 
     set([3]), 
     set([1,2]), 
     set([3]), 
     set([1,2,3])]
w = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

C = []
costs = []

def findMin(S, R):
    minCost = 99999.0
    minElement = -1
    for i, s in enumerate(S):
        try:
            cost = w[i]/(len(s.intersection(R)))
            if cost < minCost:
                minCost = cost
                minElement = i
        except:
            # Division by zero, ignore
            pass
    return S[minElement], w[minElement]

while len(R) != 0:
    S_i, cost = findMin(S, R)
    C.append(S_i)
    R = R.difference(S_i)
    costs.append(cost)

print "Cover: ", C
#print "Total Cost: ", sum(costs), costs
```

As can be seen U has values 1,2,3,4. None of the sets have 4 in them.
I don't understands weights, so have put them as 1.

Expected output: `set([1,2])`, `set([3])`, `set([1,2,3])`, or Something which covers the maximum available.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: No output, it goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there *is* no cover, because there's an extra 4. My understanding is that by definition, the set cover problem specifies that the union of all sets in `S` must be equal to `U`. So that extra 4 shouldn't be there.

Since your program doesn't halt until it finds a perfect cover (i.e. as long as `len(R) != 0`) it will never halt on this input. You're passing invalid input to the algorithm.

On a side note, I would strongly recommend against a blanket `except` clause to test for zero division. That's not a good use of `try/except`; I think this is a case where you should look before you leap.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I get the idea. One thing that comes to mind is if I add a set([4]) automatically in S, based on the rest of the input. I should be good. Also, excuse my nonsense reuse of code. :-)