# generating a set from given sets such it's intersection with all the sets is different from {}

Tags: python, set

i have been trying to figure out an effective algorithm that returns a set such as it's intersection with the given sets isn't equal to `{}`.

for example : let's say the given sets are `{1,7,4},{2,8,5},{1,3},{2,6}` the function must return the set `{1,2}` because it has an intersection point with all the given sets (the generated set needs to be as small as possible)

Comment: You can simply take the union, that way it is guaranteed to that it intersects with all sets, please reformulate your problem, and show your own attempt.

Comment: This is a guess, but I think user wants the smallest possible such set. Otherwise the problem is trivial. Needs clarification, though.

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to mention that it needs to be as optimal as possible which is why i couldn't solve it

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973126/set-cover-or-hitting-set-numpy-least-element-combinations-to-make-up-full-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brute force solution. Apparently, this is the well-known [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem [Hitting Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation).

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

A = [{1,7,4},{2,8,5},{1,3},{2,6}]
U = set.union(*A)

result = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(1, len(U)):
    combs = combinations(U, i)
    for c in combs:
        if all(set(c) & l for l in A):
            result[len(c)].append(set(c))
    if result:
        break

result
# defaultdict(list, {2: [{1, 2}]})
```

Comment: that's pretty much it thanks for this solution , i didn't know that this problem had a name

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to make the combinedSet as small as possible? If not, this would work:

```
A = [{1,7,4},{2,8,5},{1,3},{2,6}]
combinedSet = set()
for a in A:
    combinedSet |= a
print(combinedSet)
```

Alternative, more concise method as suggested in comments:

```
A = [{1,7,4},{2,8,5},{1,3},{2,6}]
combinedSet = set.union(*A)
print(combinedSet)
```

Comment: yep the set needs to be as small as possible , sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: @JimmyCarlos, fyi OP has confirmed they need smallest such set.