# How to find the least combination of tables which will cover all the column in a column -table data using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, greedy, set-cover

I have a table with 2 columns tablename and columnname, where the same column can be present in multiple tables. I'm looking for the least combination of tables where I can cover all columns. I tried greedy sets but it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Would you be able to share your current implementation, and give some info on the  expected dataframe sizes? You might also find the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942312/how-do-i-make-my-implementation-of-greedy-set-cover-faster) stackoverflow post interesting.